# Como asignar un valor a los elementos de una estructura en javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs

Un saludo a todos, estoy aprendiendo a programar en javascript y un poco de React, encontré el siguiente código que me parece interesante el cual sirve para autocompletar dentro de un área de texto(como se muestra en la imagen), mi duda es la siguiente:

1. Como puedo desplegar únicamente los valores contenido en 'name' y 'char' de la estructura item?
2. Como asigno el valor 'text' a cada uno de los elementos de la estructura sin necesidad de desplegarlo en la lista?

Lo que quiero hacer es desplegar en el listado el nombre de la variable y un texto corto, y al momento de seleccionarlo en la lista escribir el mensaje largo.

Estoy buscando una forma simple de resolver esto, ya que todavía no logro aprender a controlar estructuras mas complejas.
Saludos a todos.

[image: Ejemplo de como se despliega el código]
    Código:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactTextareaAutocomplete from "@webscopeio/react-textarea-autocomplete";
import emoji from "@jukben/emoji-search";

import "./App.css";
import "@webscopeio/react-textarea-autocomplete/style.css";

var m1 = 'mensaje m1 mensaje largo...'
var m2 = 'mensaje m2 mensaje largo...'
var b1 = 'mensaje b1 mensaje largo...'

const Item = ({ entity: { name, char, text } }) => <div>{`${name}: ${char} : ${text}`}</div>;
const Loading = ({ data }) => <div>Loading</div>;

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <ReactTextareaAutocomplete
          className="my-textarea"
          loadingComponent={Loading}
          style={{
            fontSize: "18px",
            lineHeight: "20px",
            padding: 5
          }}
          containerStyle={{
            marginTop: 20,
            width: 400,
            height: 100,
            margin: "20px auto"
          }}
          minChar={0}
          trigger={{
            ":": {
              dataProvider: token => {

              return [
                { name: "m1", char: "texto corto m1" , text : m1 },
                { name: "m2", char: "texto corto m2" , text : m2 },
                { name: "b1", char: "texto corto b1" , text : b1 }
              ];
              },
              component: Item,
              output: (item, trigger) => item.text
            }
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactTextareaAutocomplete from "@webscopeio/react-textarea-autocomplete";
import emoji from "@jukben/emoji-search";

import "./App.css";
import "@webscopeio/react-textarea-autocomplete/style.css";

function App() {
  const m1 = 'mensaje m1 mensaje largo...'
  const m2 = 'mensaje m2 mensaje largo...'
  const b1 = 'mensaje b1 mensaje largo...'
  
  // Esto es un template
  const Item = ({ entity: { name, char, text } }) => (
    <div>
      {`${name}: ${char} : ahora no saldrá 'mensaje m1 mensaje largo...' `}
    </div>;
  )
  
  const Loading = ({ data }) => <div>Loading</div>;
  
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <ReactTextareaAutocomplete
        className="my-textarea"
        loadingComponent={Loading}
        style={{
          fontSize: "18px",
          lineHeight: "20px",
          padding: 5
        }}
        containerStyle={{
          marginTop: 20,
          width: 400,
          height: 100,
          margin: "20px auto"
        }}
        minChar={0}
        trigger={{
          ":": {
            dataProvider: token => {
              return [
                // Aquí está añadiendo los datos del template
                { name: "m1", char: "texto corto m1" , text : m1 },
                { name: "m2", char: "texto corto m2" , text : m2 },
                { name: "b1", char: "texto corto b1" , text : b1 }
              ];
            },
            { /*  Usted aquí está procesando el componente que ve en su imagen */}
            component: Item,
            output: (item, trigger) => item.text
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Le recomiendo leer la guía oficial de React en español. [Guía React Español](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html)

Si no sabe que es un Template String le recomiendo. [Guía Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings)

Por último, si no sabe cómo funciona su componente:

Item es un componente que carga un "Template". Lo que usted ve en la imagen. Esta vez removí **${text}** del template para que no aparezca. Si quiere editar el *Name* y *Char*, tendrá que ir a donde le hice el comentario dentro de **trigger={{ }}**

Comment: No entiendo tu respuesta. Copias el mismo código del OP y dices *Esto es lo que tienes que modificar*. Pero no muestras cómo lo debe modificar ni cómo se vería después de modificarlo y tampoco explicas porqué debe modificarlo. Te invito a leer [answer]. Tu respuesta parece un comentario y no aporta ninguna solución. Saludos

Comment: Y la solución cual es ?

Comment: **Como puedo desplegar únicamente los valores contenido en 'name' y 'char' de la estructura item?**

`const Item = ({ entity: { name, char, text } }) => (
    <div>
      {``${name}: ${char} : ahora no saldrá 'mensaje m1 mensaje largo...' ``}
    </div>;
  )` @BetaM

Comment: Agradezco mucho su ayuda en especial a Diego, si le daré una muy buena leída a las guías para seguir aprendiendo. Espero tengan un excelente día. Saludos.